# Implement jQuery scrollTo

Tags: jquery, plugins, position, scrollto, absolute

How to use it? Trying to set up a very basic, default setting xy scroll to the absolutely positioned div.

See http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/TWEXC/1/ for a (not) working example.

The plugin's doc are here: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/TWEXC/2/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav a').click(function(){
        $.scrollTo(this.hash, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```